# How to change the colour of a ScrollView's scrollbar when the user has set dark mode on in React Native Android?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Long story short, if I use a `<ScrollView>` element while my decide doesn't have dark mode on, the scrollbar is dark grey-ish, however, if the user has dark mode on, it's lighter colour and blends with my app's background.

I was wondering if there's a simple way to change the colour of a ScrollView's scrollbar when dark mode in on in Android React Native?